# adding state monad to the haskell kv database

Tags: haskell, state-monad

Playing with an old code review here [simple-db](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24741/simple-in-memory-db). and get stuck when I added State Monad into it to further reduce the code.

I somehow feel I am not doing it correctly. `repl cmd = getCmd >>= execCmd cmd >>= displayResult >>= continue`  change the interface of `execCmd` means change all the functions along the line.

**if I follow this approach, how to get it work?**

**what's the correct way of doing the suggested refactoring using `state` Monad ?**

```
--import qualified
import Data.Map as M
import Control.Monad.State

type History = [String]

data Result = Result (Maybe String) Bool

data Command = Invalid | End | Get String | Set String String
data DB = DB (M.Map String String)


execCmd :: Command -> State DB Result
execCmd (Set key val) = do
  (db@(DB map), r) <- get
  let newMap = M.insert key val map
  put ((DB newMap), r)
  return $ Result Nothing False 
execCmd (Get key) = do
  (db@(DB map), r) <- get
  return $ Result (M.lookup key map) False 
execCmd End = do
  return $ Result Nothing True 
execCmd Invalid = do
  return $ Result Nothing False 

getCmd = getLine >>= return . parseCmd

parseCmd :: String -> Command
parseCmd s =
  case words s of
    ("set":key:value:_) -> Set key value
    ("get":key:_)       -> Get key
    ("end":_)           -> End
    _                   -> Invalid

displayResult :: Result -> IO Result
displayResult r@(Result (Just s) _ ) = putStrLn s >> return r
displayResult r                      = return r

continue :: Result -> IO ()
continue (Result _ end) = if end then return () else repl 

repl cmd = getCmd >>= execCmd cmd >>= displayResult >>= continue

startState = ((DB M.empty), (Result Nothing False))

--main = repl Invalid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, your code doesn't type check, so let's just concentrate on the first part of `execCmd`:

```
execCmd :: Command -> State DB Result
execCmd (Set key val) = do
  (db@(DB map), r) <- get
  let newMap = M.insert key val map
  put ((DB newMap), r)
  return $ Result Nothing False
```

Clearly this isn't going to work because `get` and `put` are operating with a pair `(DB, r)` but your type signature says that the state type is only a `DB`.

What is `r` here? Do you need it? This definition of `execCmd` agrees with the type signature:

```
execCmd :: Command -> State DB Result
execCmd (Set key val) = do
  db@(DB map) <- get
  let newMap = M.insert key val map
  put (DB newMap)
  return $ Result Nothing False
```